# .NET and Oracle data access

Tags: .net, oracle10g

I am trying to do something like this:

```
Public Sub (ByVal boolTest As Boolean)
Dim objConnecton As System.Data.Common.DbConnection
Try

  If boolTest Then
         objConnecton = New SqlConnection
  Else
          objConnecton = New OracleConnection 
  End If
  Catch ex As Exception

Finally
  'Cleanup here
End Try
```

This works with version 2.112.1.0, of Oracle.DataAccess, but does not with version 10.2.0.100.  With version 10.2.0.100, I get the following compilation error:

"Value of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'"

I am trying to initialise the connection object with an instance of either SQLConnection or OracleConnection depending on the value of the Boolean.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I get this error?

The later (10.2+) versions of the Oracle clients for .NET do not derive from the standard .NET framework classes, such as `DbConnection`.  This has the unfortunate side effect of requiring a fair bit more work if you want to support multiple databases seamlessly, as you can no longer just use the base classes in `System.Data.Common`.

Comment: Thanks for stating the reason for the error.  Would you use System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection instead? +1.

Comment: @w0051977 If it's functional for your uses, yes, it would be far simpler.

Comment: what do you mean by "functional" uses?

Comment: @w0051977 For most uses, the Microsoft implementation works fine.  I believe there are some Oracle-specific functionality that is exposed in the Oracle provided classes.  If you're trying to use it in this manner (where you can swap DBs at runtime), the System.Data version should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you have a look at my other question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627415/microsoft-net-and-oracle-data-access-conversion-from-type-oracledecimal-to-type

Answer (score 2):

You could use Microsoft implementation of OracleConnection  instead of Oracle one..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection(v=vs.90).aspx

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks.  I am testing this now.  Are there any risks using this approach? +1

Comment: I can't tell. Probably there could be some advanced features provided by Oracle and not implemented by Microsoft, but in the basics they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about using System.Data.IDbConnection instead?

Comment: Yes, you can declare your connection instance as IDBConnection type because Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection derives from System.Data.Common.DBConnection which implements the interface.
EDIT: Sorry, this works for me with the 2.112.1.0, version or OracleDataAccess so it looks like my comment will not apply to the original poster's question.