# Microsoft.NET and Oracle data access: Conversion from type OracleDecimal to type String is not valid

Tags: .net, oracle10g

I have the following ASP.NET program, which calls an Oracle stored procedure:

```
Dim objDBCon As New OracleConnection(strCon)
Try
    objDBCon.Open()
        Dim objDBCmd As New OracleCommand("Person.DeletePerson", objDBCon)
        objDBCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim objParam As New OracleParameter
        objParam.ParameterName = "PersonID"
        objParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
        objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        objParam.Value = PersonID
        objDBCmd.Parameters.Add(objParam)

        objParam = New OracleParameter
        objParam.ParameterName = "nReturn"
        objParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64
        objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        objDBCmd.Parameters.Add(objParam)

        objDBCmd.CommandTimeout = 30
        objDBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        strResponse = objDBCmd.Parameters("nReturn").Value
Catch ex As Exception


Finally

'Cleanup code here

End Try
```

The code works perfectly in the live environment and on my old development PC.  However, on my new development PC, an exception is thrown on the following line: strResponse = objDBCmd.Parameters("nReturn").Value.  The exception is: "Conversion from type OracleDecimal to type String is not valid.  If I change the data type of strResponse to 'Decimal', then the exception is: "Conversion from type OracleDecimal to type String is not valid".  The development PC has the following installed: Windows 7, .NET framework 3.5, Visual Studio 2008, Oracle.DataAccess version 10.2.0.100 and version 2.112.1.0.  I cannot find any information on this error.  What does it mean?

Update
I am wandering if it is because my new development pc is 64 bit windows

Comment: That seems like the same error to me?  Which would mean that strResponse is probably not the issue here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting:

```
objParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64
```

Try:

```
objParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int64
```

**Also**, you may need to change:

```
strResponse = objDBCmd.Parameters("nReturn").Value
```

To:

```
strResponse = objDBCmd.Parameters("nReturn").Value.ToString()
```

Or:

```
strResponse = objDBCmd.Parameters("nReturn").ToString()
```

Comment: Thankfully I am using VB.Net and the casting is automatic. If this was C# upgrading a large legacy project would require a lot of refactoring. The DbType methods do not work for everyone, I think there has been incompatibilities with OracleDbType back since .Net 1.1. Not happy about using the ToString() method but at least it works!